# Is there a way to have a Python program affect another app?

Tags: python

I am making an app to block other apps, to break bad habits. How would I make Python hide another app? I would like it to look sort of like [the screen time message](https://media.wired.com/photos/5ba97c1c9d86a52d3f1d01c0/master/w_1600%2Cc_limit/ScreenTime2.jpg). I cant find a way to make python affect other apps, only cover them with a Tk window. How would I do that?

Comment: What do you mean by 'block other apps'?   For people who don't know what Apple Screen time is, stating "I am making an  app to block other apps like Apple screen time" would mean nothing.  Please be clear and concise as to what exactly you're trying to do.

Comment: Well for people who don't know what Xcode is, saying "I am using Xcode" would mean nothing. It is assumed that if you are on a computer site, you know a lot about computers.

Comment: To be  fair, one may know a lot about computers does not imply that one knows every single feature on every single operating system.  Your question was about Python which I do know.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to this likely has to more to do with the iOS operating system than Python. There are ways to run shell commands from python like os.system(). And whatever framework you are using to run python on iOS might have ways of interacting with the OS.

but covering, blocking or otherwise changing the behavior of other applications is a privileged action. It is also something most mobile apps do not need to do. I wouldn't be surprised if it was impossible outside of the frameworks Apple themselves created and maintains. Apple screen time in particular might be difficult to change the behavior of, being basically a part of the OS.

Comment: the preferred way would be to use `subprocess.run` instead of `os.system` nowadays.